# .order-sm-12/1 does not work as intended Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a very simple html structure:

```
<div class="col-md-3 order-sm-last ms-auto">
        Hello!
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 order-sm-first">
        Welcome!
</div>
```

*note*: These 2 `<div>` elements are placed inside a `container` and a `row`.

Goal is to:

Have `Welcome!` being displayed after `Hello!` on large screens,
and on small screens I wanted it to display `Hello!` under `Welcome!`.

but using the code above simply puts `Hello!` after and under `Welcome!` on any type of screen respectively!

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RyanWilson The fiddle actually displays `Hello!` after `Welcome!` and not before for large screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the order class along with the order-{col size} on the divs. This works for me.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="order-2 order-md-9 col-md-9">
            Hello!
    </div>
    <div class="order-1 order-md-3 col-md-3">
            Welcome!
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the answer, and changed the order in which the number of the col-md's where, And yes that worked like a charm! Great job Ryan thank you for your help!

Comment: @JameuLukasli1 You're welcome. Glad to help